# chart.js API returns bad x and y points

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js3, chart.jsv3

I am calling my bubbleChart via chart.js API and trying to access x,y values of points but I get this very strange behavior

```
console.log(bubbleChart._metasets[1].data)
console.log(bubbleChart._metasets[1].data[0])
```

[image]

when I access object.x or object.y I get those 350.017 and 537.199 for every point even in console it shows x,y with correct values.
What is going on?

of course I tried also this, but same result

```
bubbleChart.getDatasetMeta(1).data[0]
```

here is the fiddle which show strange behavior
console.log shows always same data for different endpoints but if you put in console bubbleChart._metasets it shows correct x,y values

https://jsfiddle.net/vxb792pe/

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: there is no error, it just returns different value what is shown in screenshot....x,y doesnt match with x,y it should return

Comment: Hard for anyone to help without a [mre] that demonstrates the issue

Comment: ok I created a fiddle for this...it behaves differently than in browser but also wrong

Answer (score 0):

actually I found a workaround

```
var xAxis = bubbleChart.scales['x'];
var yAxis = bubbleChart.scales['y'];

pointx = xAxis.getPixelForValue(bubbleChart.data.datasets[i].data[0].x)
pointy = yAxis.getPixelForValue(bubbleChart.data.datasets[i].data[0].y)
```